# Why is my viewport acting strangely?

Tags: objects

I have been using blender for a few weeks onw and i came across this viewport issue that happens whenever i go to wireframe or solid mode but not on material preview or rendered. this issue moves all the object in a sort of line pattern and makes other object vanish. this glitch makes it look as if any object not on the shadow was not there. I am using cycles on gpu compute with 256 samples on the render and 32 samples on the viewport and rendering tiles of 288x and y. I have a ryzen 5 2600 on the laetst driver, an rtx 2060 running on the latest game ready driver (aka Game ready driver Version 466.27), a b450M/ac on the newwest BIOS version, and a 480Gb SSD with only 50Gb of free storage left (dont know if it matters). I experienced this issue seemingly out of nowhere and i do not know what it caused it. I do have many modifiers active and some applied on several different objects. I also have many different objects as parents. any help is appreciated.[image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you activated the [clipping region](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/regions.html) function by mistake. Just press <kbd>Alt+B</kbd> to "fix" it.